# Button text not centering

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a bunch of buttons on a very complex layout. Problem is that what ever I do, buttons won't center text inside them. I tried adding android:gravity="center", I tried setting the gravity from code, I tried removing all formatting from the button. What am I doing wrong? Text on the button needs to be centered.

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="130dp" android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- android:background="@drawable/picture_frame_94x94_suggested_matches" -->


    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/picture_unknown" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="40dp" android:id="@+id/suggest_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp" android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/suggest_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp" android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.4">
    <Button android:id="@+id/unmatch_button" android:text="Un-match" android:textColor="@color/white" 
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/nextmatch_button" android:text="@string/next" android:textColor="@color/white" 
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/donematchpicker_button" android:text="@string/done" android:textColor="@color/white" 
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp" android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/suggest_count"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp" android:textColor="@color/black"></TextView>

<include layout="@layout/facebook_list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<View android:id="@+id/list_devider" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight="0.4" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/exit_button" android:text="@string/exit" android:textColor="@color/white" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:visibility="gone" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/donematch_button" android:text="@string/done" android:textColor="@color/white" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:visibility="gone" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is XML of the dialog background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="#969798" />
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#7dd6ee" />

     <corners android:bottomRightRadius="6dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="6dp" android:topRightRadius="6dp"/>
```

screenshot: http://i39.tinypic.com/fc8aoo.png

This is sample button initialization:

```
        nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextmatch_button);
    nextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                // bunch of code
    });     
    nextButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

This is definition of button background:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_small_hover" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_small_hover" /> 
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_small2_disabled" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_small2" /> 
</selector>
```

What is causing text to be left aligned instead of centered what ever I do with it? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: just remove layout_gravity from button tag in xml & keep gravity="center" and check.

Answer (score 3):

Set the equal padding of the button like:

```
nextButton.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
```

Hope this will resolve  the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, for each button you are

android:width="wrap_content"

So whatever the length of the text, the button will not take that much space,

so there is no question of making the text center

Answer (score -1):

Try making your button of fixed width.

```
layout_width="100dip"
```

Comment: removing layout_gravity & gravity="center" didn't work. Neither did fixed width. Tx anyway.

Comment: Figured it out, I added some padding, and it started centering. Funny that it doesn't if there is no padding. But that's the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have one casual solution to do this, just give some spaces at starting and ending of the text e.g "android:text="  xyz  ".